# get unique documents with sorting in a collection

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a mongo collection 'Student' with below documents

```
`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d006ed8506fe860333c5aa2"),
    "studentId" : "123",
    "examName" : "abc",
    "marks" : 56,
    "isLatest" : 34343,
    "examStatus" : "Completed",
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2019-06-09T07:02:00.650Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d006ed8506fe860333cwewew2"),
    "studentId" : "123",
    "examName" : "abc",
    "marks" : 57,
    "isLatest" : 45454,
    "examStatus" : "Completed",
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2019-06-10T07:02:00.650Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d006ed8506fe860333c5aa5"),
    "studentId" : "123",
    "examName" : "def",
    "marks" : 56,
    "isLatest" : 4434,
    "examStatus" : "Completed",
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2019-06-10T07:02:00.650Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d006ed8506fe860333c5aa8"),
    "studentId" : "123",
    "examName" : "def",
    "isLatest" : 1,
    "examStatus" : "Under progress",
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2019-06-11T07:02:00.650Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d00708a506fe860333c5ad9"),
    "studentId" : "456",
    "examName" : "def",
    "marks" : 56,
    "isLatest" : 1,
    "examStatus" : "Completed",
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2019-06-10T07:02:00.650Z")
}`
```

Now i want to get the documents latest unique data basis on examName where examStatus is completed. For example for examName : def the query should return following document

```
`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d00708a506fe860333c5ad9"),
    "studentId" : "456",
    "examName" : "def",
    "marks" : 56,
    "isLatest" : 1,
    "examStatus" : "Completed",
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2019-06-10T07:02:00.650Z")
}`
```

And for testName "abc" it should return

```
`{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d006ed8506fe860333cwewew2"),
    "studentId" : "123",
    "examName" : "abc",
    "marks" : 57,
    "isLatest" : 45454,
    "examStatus" : "Completed",
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2019-06-10T07:02:00.650Z")
}`
```

and in case the document with exam status underprogess changes to completed as below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d006ed8506fe860333c5aa8"),
    "studentId" : "123",
    "examName" : "def",
    "marks" : 99,
    "isLatest" : 1,
    "examStatus" : "Completed",
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2019-06-11T07:02:00.650Z")
}
```

Then the output of students for examName def and examStatus completed should return me

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d00708a506fe860333c5ad9"),
    "studentId" : "456",
    "examName" : "def",
    "marks" : 56,
    "isLatest" : 1,
    "examStatus" : "Completed",
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2019-06-10T07:02:00.650Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d006ed8506fe860333c5aa8"),
    "studentId" : "123",
    "examName" : "def",
    "marks" : 99,
    "isLatest" : 1,
    "examStatus" : "Completed",
    "addedOn" : ISODate("2019-06-11T07:02:00.650Z")
}
```

the below query i tried so far

`db.getCollection('Student').aggregate([
{ "$sort" : { "addedOn" : -1}},
{ "$match" : {"examName" : "def"} }
])`

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach,

```
db.Student.find({examName:"def", examStatus:"Completed"}).sort({addedOn : -1}).limit(1)
```

Otherwise To get latest value you can sort by ObjectId. You can do this because 4-byte value of ObjectId represents the seconds since the Unix epoch,

```
db.Student.find({examName:"def", examStatus:"Completed"}).sort({_id : -1}).limit(1)
```

**Updated**

I think you can't do this by one query. try using two queries,

```
var student = db.Student.findOne({examName:"abc", examStatus:"Completed"})
db.Student.find({"addedOn" : {$gte : student.addedOn}, "examName" : {$eq : student.examName}, "examStatus" : {$eq : student.examStatus}});
```

Comment: this will always give me only one document. document with id changes examstatus from under process to completed then the output should be document with these ids `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d00708a506fe860333c5ad9")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d006ed8506fe860333c5aa8")
}

Comment: If you need multiple documents just remove that limit(1) function. then it will give all relevant documents.

Comment: then it will give all three documents having two documents for studentId:123 but for this i need only one with the latest addedOn

Comment: Now i understand your issue. I've edited the answer. try that.